# Prevent content getting covered changing from relative header to fixed header

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a relative positioned header and when the user scrolls down the page, I want to shift to a fixed header. This is working fine except that the header ends up covering the element the user had scrolled to. Is it possible to prevent this so that the gap between the header and the element remains the same for a seamless transition?

```js
$(function() {
  var hh = $('header').outerHeight();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var last = 0;
    if (scroll >= hh) {
      $('body').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('body').removeClass('sticky');
    }
    last = scroll;
  });
});
```

```css
body,html {
  margin:0;
}
.site-container {
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  height:1500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:gray;
}

img {
  width:100%;
}

header {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%;
  background:white;
}

body.sticky header {
  position:fixed;
  width:inherit;
}

.top-bar {
  background:purple;
  color:white;
  padding:3px 0;
  text-align:right;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
  padding-left:10px;
  list-style-type:none;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
  line-height:30px;
}
li:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}

.site-content {
  padding:50px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-container">
  <header>
    <div class="top-bar">(555) 555-5555</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="site-content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400/0000FF/808080" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution using css only, without jQuery needed.
Try css property "position: sticky" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
body,html {
  margin:0;
}
.site-container {
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  height:1500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:gray;
}

img {
  width:100%;
}

header {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.top-bar {
  background:purple;
  color:white;
  padding:3px 0;
  text-align:right;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
  padding-left:10px;
  list-style-type:none;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
  line-height:30px;
}
li:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}

.site-content {
  padding:50px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-container">
  <header>
    <div class="top-bar">(555) 555-5555</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="site-content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400/0000FF/808080" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I would like for it to start out in a relative position and not stick to the top until the user scrolls down past the height of the header

Comment: In case you want to keep existing behaviour with jQuery, you can conditionally add css style for `.site-content ` when `body` is sticky.

Here is an example  - https://codepen.io/AlphaOmegaBetaGamma/pen/NWYLZQW

Answer (score 0):

The website: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp has the steps to create a fixed header on scroll. This should help with additional styling that might need to be added to make your header flow without blinking like @Oleg 's simulation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).